# Find values from equations with complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I'm having a issue with solving this problem. I know that the answer is $ a=3, b=1 $. But i'm not sure how to get to that conclusion.

Given that $(a+i)(2-bi)=7-i$, find the value of $a$ and of $b$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$(a+i)(2-bi) = 7-i\Rightarrow 2a+2i-abi-bi^2 = 7-i\;,$$ Now Using $i^2=-1$

So $$(2a+b)+i(2-ab) = 7+i(-1)\;,$$ After camparing Real and Imaginary part, we get

$$2a+b=7.......(1)$$ and $$2-ab=-1\Rightarrow ab=3.....(2)$$

Put $b=7-2a$ in $ab=3\;,$ We get $a(7-2a)=3\Rightarrow 7a-2a^2=3$

So we get $$2a^2-7a+3=0\Rightarrow 2a^2-6a-a+3=0\Rightarrow (a-3)\cdot (2a-1)=0$$

So we get $a=3\in \mathbb{Z}$. So we get $b=1$

Comment: You forgot $a = 1/2$ and $b = 6$.

Comment: Oups, I didn't see that $a$ and $b$ should be integers.

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that, if $(a+bi)(c+di)=(e+fi)$, then $(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)=e^2+f^2$ (that is, the norm on complex numbers is multiplicative).

Applying that to the equation you're given, you have
$$
(a^2+1)(4+b^2)=49^2+1^2=50
$$
So $a^2+1$ and $b^2+4$ must be complimentary factors of $50$.

The only factor of $50$ which is $4$ more than a perfect square is $5$. So we must have $b^2+4=5$, $a^2+1=10$, making $b=\pm 1$, $a=\pm 3$. This gives you four possible solutions; try all of them to see which works.